# react createref was returning the error due to wrong implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-ref

**This is the edited question after submitting the answer**

In this code, my file browser will now directly open but when I am submiting the final button then I am not getting the updated state.

uploadImage() will be converting the image to base 64 and then update the value on the state.

uploadCode() will be used to final send the data after clicking on submit button. I have checked that I am not getting the updated value of state in this function according to this logic i.e label & htmlFor.

My earlier logic was fine when click on upload image div then set the state variable show image from false to true; Choose file button only visible when state is true. Rest all implementation is same and that was working fine. But now I am be able to getting the updated state that is why when submit button click I am not getting the image as state is not updated.

```
 constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.inputFile = React.createRef()
    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
}
uploadImage = (e) => {
    console.log('function called')
/*************New Edit*************/
// getting the image through base64 string and then update it on state;
this.setState({image: myBase64String}, () => { console.log(this.state.image )});
// Return the string through above console
  }

uploadCode = () => {
const {image} = this.state;
console.log(image);//returns undefined;
}
render(){
 return (
    <div><Button onClick={()=>this.uploadCode()} >SUBMIT</Button></div>
      <div className={cx(styles['display-tablecell'], styles['pl-lg'])}>
        <FormControl
          style={{display: 'none'}}
          id="formControlsFile"
          type="file"
          label="File"
          onChange={this.uploadImage}
          name="image"
          ref={this.inputFile}
        />
        <label
          style={{display: 'inline-block'}}
          // onClick={this.onButtonClick}
          htmlFor="formControlsFile" <---- binding to the input tag using the same id
        >
          <i className={cx(fontStyles.fa, fontStyles['fa-image'])} />
        </label>
      </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to open the file explorer when user clicks on the `<span />`. However, you do not need to simulate the `click` behaviour to achieve that. You can make use of the html `<label />` tag to bind the `onclick` functionality of `<input type="file" />`. Here's how -

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    /* You won't need these
    this.inputFile = React.createRef()
    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this)
    */
  }

  uploadImage = (e) => {
    console.log('function called')
/*************New Edit*************/
// getting the image through base64 string and then update it on state;
this.setState({image: myBase64String}, () => { console.log(this.state.image )});
// Return the string through above console
  }

  /* You won't need these
  onButtonClick = () => {
    console.log('div clicked')
    this.inputFile.current.click()
  }
  */
uploadCode = () => {
const {image} = this.state;
console.log(image);//returns undefined;
}
  render() {
    return (
<div><Button onClick={()=>this.uploadCode()} >SUBMIT</Button></div>
      <div className={cx(styles['display-tablecell'], styles['pl-lg'])}>
        <FormControl
          style={{display: 'none'}}
          id="formControlsFile"
          type="file"
          label="File"
          onChange={this.uploadImage}
          name="image"
          ref={this.inputFile}
        />
        <label
          style={{display: 'inline-block'}}
          // onClick={this.onButtonClick}
          htmlFor="formControlsFile" <---- binding to the input tag using the same id
        >
          <i className={cx(fontStyles.fa, fontStyles['fa-image'])} />
        </label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can find more information about `<label />` tag [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Comment: Hey @himayan, I have added the code on the snippet. I am not getting the state value after using the suggested solution. Can you get suggest me why this thing not working as I have only change the click behaviour. Rest all are same. If I get back to my previous solution, then I do not have state issue

Comment: I am not getting the updated state on the uploadCode(). 
uploadCode() -> checked that state is being updated successfully but when chcek on uploadCode() then not getting the updated state.
uploadImage() will call when user upload the image. uploadCode() called when user hit the submit button.

Can you help me out to get why my state is not updated.